# Как отправить файл на сайт, при нажатии на input через Python

Tags: python, файлы, post, requests, отправка

Как реализовать **отправку файла**, к примеру по такому адресу: https://www.imgonline.com.ua/ocr.php
Когда мы нажимаем на кнопку обзор (`<input type="file" name="uploadfile">`) мы выбираем файл и после нажатия на кнопку ок. Мы получаем определённый результат. Можно ли реализовать это на **Python** **(не используя Selenium)** ?

Comment: Можно. Если смотреть html, там есть тег `<form action="ocr-result.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. Нужно все параметры, которые внутри этого тега задаются отправить post-запросом на url www.imgonline.com.ua/ocr-result.php , например с помощью библиотеки requests

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё сделал.